# Modal dialog message truncated in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using a Modal dialog to prompt user a message. It works fine in IE but shows only first row in firefox. How can i fix this. This is how my message is formatted.

```
 var modal = "<div id='modal_pop'><table><tr><td> "                    
           + "Please check you have a valid value to proceed.<br> Change the value if possible. Value should be valid to proceed further.<br>"
           + "Value should not be a number or a special case character<br>
Make changes and save the work before exiting it.<br>  " 
           + "Click logoff now or continute using the application.</td> </tr> </table></div>";
```

and this is the jQuery dialog:

```
var showPopup = function() {
            $(modal).dialog({
                buttons: {
                    "Test": function() {
                                        //ABC
                                      },
                    "Test1": function() {
                                        //XYZ
                                     }
                },
                 modal: true,
             width: 430,
         height: 100,
         resizable:'yes',
         scroll:'no'
               });
        }
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net is a perfect place to show your demo

Answer (score 1):

try to set the width to auto `width: 'auto'` and check. I think the text is getting cut because of overflow.

Comment: is it that the pop up has many rows and only first row is displayed?